# Problem when passing as argument a std::bind of a member function on C++ (and MoveIt API)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, boost, stdbind

Good day,

NOTE: *Although this is a ROS related question, I post it here because I am quite sure my problem is with C++ and not with ROS API.*

I am trying to use the function [setFromIK](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_core/html/classmoveit_1_1core_1_1RobotState.html#ab816880027ef7e63bbdef22a0497cc78) defined on [moveit::core::RobotState](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_core/html/classmoveit_1_1core_1_1RobotState.html#a7dab73858059bedb7894cf4ec520c10d).

This function admits a callable parameter named `GroupStateValidityCallbackFn` with type (function signature):

[`typedef boost::function<bool(RobotState* robot_state, const JointModelGroup* joint_group, const double* joint_group_variable_values)>`](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_core/html/namespacemoveit_1_1core.html#a7e30b6ca7b8fafe9e2dd276d60e00b2c)

The problem arises because I am trying to pass a member class functions to this parameter (because I need come class instance member fields in the processing), and then the binding process goes to hell.

My class look like this:

```
class CSDA10F{
    public:
       bool validateIKSolution( robot_state::RobotState* robot_state, 
                                        const robot_state::JointModelGroup* joint_group, 
                                        const double* joint_group_variable_value){
              [...]
              // some code here
              [...]
          }

       bool planCartesianMotionTask(MoveGroupInterface* move_group, 
                                                    geometry_msgs::Pose initial_pose, 
                                                    geometry_msgs::Pose final_pose,
                                                    std::vector<MoveGroupInterface::Plan> motion_plans,
                                                    uint max_configurations = 10) {
         [...] // Here I make the call!!!.
            auto ik_check_callback = std::bind(&CSDA10F::validateIKSolution, this, _1, _2, _3);
            ik_solution_found = start_state.setFromIK( joint_model_group, initial_pose, 10, 0.01, ik_check_callback);
         [...]
         }
```

I use 3 placeholders for the 3 arguments from the function, but then the compiler just failes with an error that I simply dont understand.

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:28:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:62,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:64,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/forwards.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/invite/catkin_ws/src/invite-robotics/drum_automation/src/bag_handling.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static R boost::detail::function::function_obj_invoker3<FunctionObj, R, T0, T1, T2>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0, T1, T2) [with FunctionObj = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (invite_utils::CSDA10F::*)(moveit::core::RobotState*, const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*, const double*)>(invite_utils::CSDA10F, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>)>; R = bool; T0 = moveit::core::RobotState*; T1 = const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*; T2 = const double*]’:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:940:38:   required from ‘void boost::function3<R, T1, T2, T3>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (invite_utils::CSDA10F::*)(moveit::core::RobotState*, const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*, const double*)>(invite_utils::CSDA10F, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>)>; R = bool; T0 = moveit::core::RobotState*; T1 = const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*; T2 = const double*]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:728:7:   required from ‘boost::function3<R, T1, T2, T3>::function3(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (invite_utils::CSDA10F::*)(moveit::core::RobotState*, const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*, const double*)>(invite_utils::CSDA10F, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>)>; R = bool; T0 = moveit::core::RobotState*; T1 = const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*; T2 = const double*; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1077:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (invite_utils::CSDA10F::*)(moveit::core::RobotState*, const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*, const double*)>(invite_utils::CSDA10F, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>)>; R = bool; T0 = moveit::core::RobotState*; T1 = const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*; T2 = const double*; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/home/invite/catkin_ws/src/invite-robotics/invite_utils/include/invite_utils/csda10f_interface.h:202:116:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:138:22: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<bool (invite_utils::CSDA10F::*)(moveit::core::RobotState*, const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*, const double*)>(invite_utils::CSDA10F, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>)>) (moveit::core::RobotState*, const moveit::core::JointModelGroup*, const double*)’
           return (*f)(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS);
```

Does the declaration on the `RobotState` does not allow for member functions?, I believe I am making a mistake with std::bind but I cannot seem to find an aswer of what it is.

What do I know:

- I am using the correct argument types in the function to be bind
- I have the correct number of arguments (3)

Any ideas what is the problem?

Comment: It looks like you are mixing the Boost `_1`, `_2`, `_3` placeholders with `std::bind`. Try switching to `boost::bind` or adding `using std::placeholders;` right before the call

Comment: Jesus what a stupid mistake I made, THANK you so much you where right. I have to tell you, you solved in 15 seconds a problem that has been bothering me for more than 6 hours.

Comment: Do you want to place your comment as an answer so I can set is as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing the Boost `_1`, `_2`, `_3` placeholders with `std::bind`. Try one of the following:

- Switching to `boost::bind`,
- Adding `using std::placeholders;` right before the call,
- Using a lambda expression that captures `this`.